# typescript in visual studio 2017 webform doesn't build js file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use typescript in a webform project.  I create the ts file but when I build the js file is not created.  I have a tsconfig.json file created and it looks like this.

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "obj",
    "bin"
  ]
}
```

just not having any luck getting the js to bulid.  This is visual studio community edition.
Thanks
shannon

Here is the new config file. This is working

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "obj",
    "bin"
  ],
  "include": [ "/CustomControls/Lookup" ]
}
```

Comment: In the Properties pane, is the Build Action set to TypeScriptCompile for your .ts file?

Comment: this is a webform, not a web app.. if that makes a difference.  when i have the .ts file selected, in the properties window it only says the filename and path.  a Test.js.map file is created.  However, when i bring up the page and look at the sources in Chrome, there is no javascript file created.  So it still does not appear to be creating the js file.. There is no js file created.

Comment: I never did find the TypeScriptCompile Build Action but the ts file is not compiling I think becuase of the entry in the config file suggested by Ken Tucker below.  I had an error in my typescript file that was causing it not to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your script path.  You only have an exclude section in the json file.  For example

```
   "include":  ["wwwroot/lib"]
```

Comment: I added an include, it is point to the subdirectory that the ts file is in.. for this testing that looks like    "include": [ "/CustomControls/Lookup" ].  I'll put the full code in the question.. don't want a syntax error getting in the way

Comment: As mentioned above.  I've included the "Include" you mentioned above, fixed the typescript scripting error i had and now the ts file is getting a .js compiled file.   So it appears things are working.  Thank you.